# невозможно вытащить данные из json

Tags: json

Помогите докапаться до "answer_text" перебором.

Уже и `['answers'][0][0]` пытался, и `['answers'][0]['answer_text']`.

Как проверить на undefined?

Ответ только: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Вот перебор:

```
$.each(ticketsArr,function(i,data) {

$('.tickets .caps').append('<li class="cap '+(i==0?'active':'')+'"><a href="#">'+parseInt(i+1)+'</a></li>')
$('.tickets .tabs').append(
                                '<div class="tab '+(i==0?'active':'')+'">'+
                                    data['title']+
                                    '<div class="image" style="background: url(/wp-content/themes/reboot_child/'+data['image']+') no-repeat center center"></div>'+
                                    data['question']+

                                        $.each(data['answers'],function(ii){
                                            (!!ii?
                                                '<div class="answer">\
                                                    <a href="#">'+data['answers'][ii]['answer_text']+'</a>\
                                                </div>':'')
                                        })+
                                    
                                '</div>'
                            );
});
```

Что надо дописать?

Через точку - как к объектам - НИКАК, ну просто НЕТ,.. консоли ответ.

Вот масс, собственно:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Вопрос 1",
    "ticket_number": "Билет 1",
    "ticket_category": "A,B",
    "image": "./images/no_image.jpg",
    "question": "В каком случае водитель совершит вынужденную остановку?",
    "answers": [
      {
        "answer_text": "Остановившись непосредственно перед пешеходным переходом, чтобы уступить дорогу пешеходу",
        "is_correct": false
      },
      {
        "answer_text": "Остановившись на проезжей части из-за технической неисправности транспортного средства",
        "is_correct": true
      },
      {
        "answer_text": "В обоих перечисленных случаях",
        "is_correct": false
      }
    ],
    "correct_answer": "Правильный ответ: 2",
    "answer_tip": "«Вынужденная остановка» - прекращение движения транспортного средства, связанное с его технической неисправностью, опасностью, создаваемой перевозимым грузом, состоянием водителя (пассажира) или появления препятствия на дороге.(Пункт 1.2 ПДД, термин «Вынужденная остановка»)",
    "topic": [
      "Общие положения"
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: Вместо `data['answers'][ii]['answer_text']` попробуйте `ii.answer_text`

Comment: @XelaNimed, не вариант, у функции, которая передается в `each`, первый аргумент -- индекс, поэтому вариант автора рабочий, просто ошибка в другом

Answer (score 1):

Без jQuery...

```js
let data = [
  {
    "title": "Вопрос 1",
    "ticket_number": "Билет 1",
    "ticket_category": "A,B",
    "image": "./images/no_image.jpg",
    "question": "В каком случае водитель совершит вынужденную остановку?",
    "answers": [
      {
        "answer_text": "Остановившись непосредственно перед пешеходным переходом, чтобы уступить дорогу пешеходу",
        "is_correct": false
      },
      {
        "answer_text": "Остановившись на проезжей части из-за технической неисправности транспортного средства",
        "is_correct": true
      },
      {
        "answer_text": "В обоих перечисленных случаях",
        "is_correct": false
      }
    ],
    "correct_answer": "Правильный ответ: 2",
    "answer_tip": "\"Вынужденная остановка\" - прекращение движения транспортного средства, связанное с его технической неисправностью, опасностью, создаваемой перевозимым грузом, состоянием водителя (пассажира) или появления препятствия на дороге.(Пункт 1.2 ПДД, термин \"Вынужденная остановка\")",
    "topic": [
      "Общие положения"
    ],
  }
].forEach(function(item){
  item.answers.forEach(function(answer){
    console.log("Text: %s", answer.answer_text);
    console.log("Correct: %o", answer.is_correct);
    console.log("-------------------------------");
  });
});
```

Comment: работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема не в том, как обратиться к объекту json, а в том, какие вы пути для вывода используете. Если вы обратили внимание, внутренний `each` даже теги не возвращает. Честно, не знаю и не нашел, что возвращает метод `each`, но скорее всего это объекты `jQuery`, которые у Вас и отображались.

Попробуйте вот такой вариант:

```js
$.each(ticketsArr,function(i,data) {
  $('.tickets .caps').append('<li class="cap '+(i==0?'active':'')+'"><a href="#">'+parseInt(i+1)+'</a></li>')
  let answers = ''
  $.each(data['answers'],function(ii){
    answers += '<div class="answer">\<a href="#">'+ data['answers'][ii]['answer_text'] +'</a>\</div>'
  })
  $('.tickets .tabs').append('<div class="tab '+(i==0?'active':'')+'">'+ data['title']+'<div class="image" style="background: url(/wp-content/themes/reboot_child/'+data['image']+') no-repeat center center"></div>'+data['question'] + answers + '</div>');
});
```